# Getting "Failure when accessing a lock file: java.io.IOException" with Artemis 2.17.0 and openjdk-1.8.0.302

Tags: activemq-artemis

```
2022-03-01 01:28:16,860 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] Failure when accessing a lock file: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the file specified
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:107) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1114) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.tryLock(FileLockNodeManager.java:389) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.lock(FileLockNodeManager.java:408) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.getState(FileLockNodeManager.java:349) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager.access$500(FileLockNodeManager.java:36) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager$MonitorLock.run(FileLockNodeManager.java:516) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.runForExecutor(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:313) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.bookedRunForScheduler(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:328) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.runForScheduler(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:339) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQScheduledComponent.lambda$start$0(ActiveMQScheduledComponent.java:166) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
```

After getting the above error artemis server is going down with `java.io.IOException: An unexpected network error occurred`:

```
2022-03-01 02:00:10,690 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222010: Critical IO Error, shutting down the server. file=NIOSequentialFile \\shared-path\activemq-bindings-2.bindings, message=An unexpected network error occurred: ActiveMQIOErrorException[errorType=IO_ERROR message=An unexpected network error occurred]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile.internalWrite(NIOSequentialFile.java:410) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile.writeDirect(NIOSequentialFile.java:374) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile.write(AbstractSequentialFile.java:239) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.AbstractSequentialFile.write(AbstractSequentialFile.java:252) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.appendRecord(JournalImpl.java:2939) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.access$100(JournalImpl.java:92) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl$7.run(JournalImpl.java:1255) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An unexpected network error occurred
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:75) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:211) [rt.jar:1.8.0_302]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile.doInternalWrite(NIOSequentialFile.java:434) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.io.nio.NIOSequentialFile.internalWrite(NIOSequentialFile.java:406) [artemis-journal-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Thanks, this information is useful. We are still not able to confirm that the network issue caused this problem. We are still working with the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These exceptions are coming from the underlying `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` provided by the JVM. There's nothing that ActiveMQ Artemis can do about them except report the failures and respond accordingly. From what I can tell everything is working as designed from the broker's point of view. Disk related failures like the ones you are experiencing are generally considered to be "critical" which means the broker will shut itself down when it encounters such an error.

Since the `java.io.IOException` is reporting "An unexpected network error occurred" it looks like you're using a network-based filesystem (e.g. NFS). If so, I recommend you ensure the integrity of this filesystem and of the network that allows connectivity from the broker.

Comment: Yes the Artemis goes down when there is a temporary network issue. But, should it not auto recover once the connectivity is restored? What I see in my testing is Artemis doesn't resume unless the service is manually restarted.

Comment: Whether or not ActiveMQ Artemis _should_ auto-recover once NFS connectivity is restored is debatable, but the fact of the matter is that it doesn't recover and wasn't designed to recover. Once the broker stops it has no way to monitor NFS connectivity. Perhaps this could be changed in the future, but at this point the recommended solution would be to configure the broker as a service so that it is restarted by the operating system if it stops for any reason. This is supported by most (if not all) major platforms so should be straightforward.

Comment: Of course, stabilizing the network between the broker and the NFS server would be the ideal solution to avoid the problem in the first place.